# How do I access environment variables from MIT Scheme?

Tags: scheme, mit-scheme

Suppose I set an environment variable in bash before starting MIT Scheme (e.g. `export FOO=123`). How can I get the value of the environment variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(get-environment-variable "FOO")
```

The remarks on https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-98/srfi-98.html state that MIT Scheme defines this function.